# i can not send message to mobile via Amazon SNS in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, amazon-sns

I want to send an sms to the user via Amazon SNS. I wrote the following code in vb.net but the error occurred:

> "The message attribute 'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' has an invalid message attribute type, the set of supported type prefixes is Binary, Number, and String."

My code on button click event is:

```
 Imports Amazon.SimpleNotificationService
 Imports Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model

 Public Class Form1
     Dim myclient As New AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient

     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim snsreq As New PublishRequest
        Dim snsres As New PublishResponse
        Dim snsmsgstng As New Dictionary(Of String, MessageAttributeValue)()
        snsmsgstng.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", New MessageAttributeValue() With {.StringValue = "testing", .DataType = "string"})
        snsmsgstng.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", New MessageAttributeValue() With {.StringValue = "Promotional", .DataType = "string"})
        snsreq.MessageAttributes = snsmsgstng
        snsreq.PhoneNumber = "+972543784512"     'phone No
        snsreq.Message = "you get message ,if yes then tells me???.."
        snsres = myclient.Publish(snsreq)
     End Sub
End Class
```

And I add the following code in app.config file

```
<appSettings  >
  <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="MYAWSAccessKey" />
  <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="MYAWSSecretKey"/>
  <add key="AWSRegion" value="ap-southeast-1"/>
</appSettings>
```

I don't know where the problem is in the code.